# CSV to CSV comparison utility

Tags: java, csv

I am working on a project where I need to compare 2 CSVs for equality. Its just a single row in each CSV with multiple columns and report the differences in form of columna name and value which are different. For eg :

```
CSV 1 : 
Name   Roll No  Dept
Brij   1        IT

CSV 2 :
Name   Roll No  Dept
Brij   2        IT

I need to report the diff as 
Roll No 1 does not match Roll No 2 i.e. Col name and value in both csvs

My work till now : 
@Test
    public void f() {
        try {
            FileReader reader1 = new FileReader(
                    new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\resources\\csvFile\\Reader.csv"));
            FileReader reader2 = new FileReader(
                    new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\resources\\csvFile\\Reader - Copy.csv"));

            CSVReader csvReader1 = new CSVReader(reader1);
            CSVReader csvReader2 = new CSVReader(reader2);
            String[] nextRecordReader1;
            String[] nextRecordReader2;
            // we are going to read data line by line
            while ((nextRecordReader1 = csvReader1.readNext()) != null
                    && (nextRecordReader2 = csvReader2.readNext()) != null) {
                checkEquality(nextRecordReader1, nextRecordReader2);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void checkEquality(String[] s1, String[] s2) {
        if (s1 == s2) {}

        if (s1 == null || s2 == null) {}

        int n = s1.length;
        if (n != s2.length) {}

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (!s1[i].trim().equals(s2[i].trim())) {
                System.out.println(s1[i] + " is not equal to " + s2[i]);
            }
        }

    }
```

This gives me the below result :
1 is not equal to 2

I am not able to mention the column name. How shall I do that ?

Comment: Your file is not a CSV, it's a Tab Separated Value, since in the CSV format, you don't have any columns, just print out the first line for the column name

Answer (score 0):

```
public void checkEquality(String[] s1, String[] s2) {
        if (s1 == s2) {}

        if (s1 == null || s2 == null) {}

        String[] headers= new String[]{"Name","Roll No","Dept"};
        int n = s1.length;
        if (n != s2.length) {}

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (!s1[i].trim().equals(s2[i].trim())) {
                System.out.println(headers[i]+" "+s1[i] + " is not equal to " headers[i]+"  "+ s2[i]);
            }
        }

    }
```

You need a collection to hold column headers, and use this collection to get header based on index.

Comment: What if the column headers are dynamic ?

Comment: In such case populate this collection once you start reading csv files

Comment: Also, I would need to compare the headers first as well

Comment: 2 steps check is what you need here. First, compare first row of both csv files(compare headers) and if Check 1 is clean proceed row wise match starting from  row no 2 of both files.

Comment: Have answered my question. Kindly review it and let me know for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
    enter code here


public class SampleTest {
    int rowCountCounter;
    String[] headers1;
    String[] headers2;

    @Test
    public void f() {
        try {
            FileReader reader1 = new FileReader(
                    new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\resources\\csvFile\\Reader.csv"));
            FileReader reader2 = new FileReader(
                    new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\resources\\csvFile\\Reader - Copy.csv"));

            CSVReader csvReader1 = new CSVReader(reader1);
            CSVReader csvReader2 = new CSVReader(reader2);
            String[] nextRecordReader1;
            String[] nextRecordReader2;
            rowCountCounter=0;
            // we are going to read data line by line
            while ((nextRecordReader1 = csvReader1.readNext()) != null
                    && (nextRecordReader2 = csvReader2.readNext()) != null) {
                if(rowCountCounter==0) {
                    headers1=nextRecordReader1;
                    headers2=nextRecordReader2;
                }
                checkEquality(nextRecordReader1, nextRecordReader2);
                rowCountCounter++;
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void checkEquality(String[] s1, String[] s2) {
        if (s1 == s2) {}

        if (s1 == null || s2 == null) {}

        int n = s1.length;
        if (n != s2.length) {
            System.out.println("Header in CSV1 " + n + " is not equal to header in CSV2 " + s2.length);
        }
        boolean headerFlag=true;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if(rowCountCounter==0) {
                if (!s1[i].trim().equals(s2[i].trim())) {
                    System.out.println("CSV1 header "+s1[i] + " is not equal to CSV2 header " + s2[i]);
                    headerFlag=false;
                }
            }else {
                if (!s1[i].trim().equals(s2[i].trim())) {
                    System.out.println("CSV1 "+headers1[i] +" cellvalue "+" \"" +s1[i] +"\"" +" is not equal to CSV2 " + headers2[i]+" value \""+s2[i]+"\"");
                    headerFlag=false;
                }
//              else {
//                  System.out.println("CSV data is equal");
//              }

            }

        }
        if(headerFlag==true && rowCountCounter==0) {
            System.out.println("CSV headers are equal.Below are the headers");
            for(int k=0;k<s1.length;k++) {
                System.out.print(s1[k]+" ");
            }
        }

        if(headerFlag==true && rowCountCounter!=0) {
            System.out.println("CSV data is equal.");
        }

    }
}
```